# How to extract value in "optional(value)"

Tags: swift, command-line

I am trying to retrieve a value that is in an Optional(N) where "N" is the value. I am new to Swift, so I am not sure if I have the syntax right or if it is even recommended to write my code like this, but heres what I have:

```
func dmg_Calc() {
if player.SPD < opponent.SPD   {
    var XX = rndm(2, 3)
    var A = opponent.Lvl
    var B = opponent.ATT
    var C = opponent.MOV[XX]?[1]
    var D = player.ATT
    var X = 1.0
    var Y = 1.0
    var Z = rndm_DBL(217.0, 255.0)


    // Opponent Attacks

    var DMG = ((2.0*A/5.0+2.0)*B)
        DMG = (DMG/D/50.0)+2.0
        DMG = DMG*(X*Y/10.0)*Z/255.0

    player.HP = (player.HP - DMG)

    println(C)
    println(DMG)
    println("HP Left \(player.HP)")
    println(XX)
}
}
```

I am using this as a damage calculation as I can see. My problem is when you get to Var C. That line gives me an Optional(N). It is basically routing to a dict to an array with the needed values.

```
class Eevee {
var Lvl = 5.0
var HP = 20.0
var ATT = 55.0
var DEF = 15.0
var SPD = 16.0
var SPC = 15.0
var isPoisoned = false
var isParalyzed = false
var isAsleep = false
var MOV = [1 : ["Tackle", 40.0, 35], 2 : ["Tail Whip", 0.9, 35]]
```

The above is the class that the function is accessing. I know it may look messy or terrible, but its what I am working with at the moment.

Is what I want possible to be done or should I try a different method? Any help would be appreciated!!!

EDIT:

Now I get the following error in Xcode:

'NSObject' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

Here is the new equation:

```
var DMG = ((2.0*A/5.0+2.0)*B*C)
        DMG = (DMG/D/50.0)+2.0
        DMG = DMG*(X*Y/10.0)*Z/255.0
```

Comment: Next time please remove all unnecessary code for better readability.

Comment: Please say which line of those 3.........................

Comment: The first. The one with C

Comment: When calculating with an optional you need to tell it that it is not nil by doing the same thing I said in my answer. Because C is an optional it acnnot be sure if C is nil or not so it wont take that chance and give you an error instad. However, the errors in Swift is still very missleading.

Answer (score 0):

When printing out an optional and you know its not nil you would want to put a ! after what you want to print out

```
println(C!)
```

It only say Optional(value) when printing it or when inserting it into a string like "(optionalString)" so you dont have to "extract" it.

An optional variable is basically telling the program that this variable can be nil when used.

[Please read Swift basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: Thats nice to know! But I am wanting to place C in that big Equation and so one value is 40 and the equation doesnt change. Would that value still apply or would it multiply by optional(40)?

Comment: Okay that totally works but I ran into a new issue. I am editing the post now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got an optional is because a dictionary may not contain the key you search for, a nil optional in this context means "not in dictionary". If you are confident that XX will always be in MOV then use opponent.MOV[XX]![1].

Note: change of ? to ! (if XX isn't in MOV then you will get a fatal error at runtime!). The use of !, pronounced bang, is meant to warn you - are you really sure about this?

Note 2: if the array doesn't have an item at index 1 then you will also get a fatal error at runtime.

Comment: Yes I am sure that XX will always be in MOV. MOV will hold 4 moves with attack power and # of times able to be used. Your method also helped but I have a new error that I edited above.

Comment: You have an array of Any, you probably want to define something like struct Action{ name: String; value1: Float; value2: Float }. Then MOV is [1 : Action("Tackle", 40.0, 35), 2 : Action("Tail Whip", 0.9, 35)]

Comment: Do I still declare MOV as a Var?

Comment: It depends if you are going to modify MOV.

Comment: Yes down the road I would like to modify Mov

Comment: You appear to be basically asking people to write your code. No wonder you are getting down voted. All these questions are in the first section of the Swift book.

Comment: Okay then would you be so kind to show me where on the first section my question is answered.

Comment: 1st sub-section, Simple Values, in 1st chapter, A Swift Tour, describes let and var. You are precisely 6 paragraphs into the 1st chapter when you latest question is directly addressed.

Comment: I have my code like it is shown, but when I get to where Variable C is in the equation I have an error saying 'double' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<Int, Array<NSObject>>' so what would you make of that. And I seriously appreciate you helping me out.